# Existe == o === en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

He buscado la pregunta, a ver si aparece algo al respecto, pero creo que no lo he visto, si es así me disculpo de antemano.

El punto es el siguiente, tengo una consulta en mysql donde en teoría me debería mostrar 2 valores, de lo contrario, no mostrar nada.

En mi base de datos hay tipos de inmuebles(apartamento o departamentos, casas, etc) y tipos de operaciones (venta, alquiler, etc.).

Tengo es un buscador sobre mi base de datos, donde lo que hago es recibir, la información desde mi formulario y esto debería arrojarme lo que necesito.

Por ejemplo si en mi formulario $tipo = 'apartamento' y $operacion = 'venta', me debería mostrar solamente eso, pero el caso es que me muestra todos los inmuebles en venta, aunque no sean apartamentos. Esta es la sentencia:

```
$busqueda = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM inmuebles WHERE operacion = '$operacion' AND tipo = '$tipo' ORDER BY precio_dolar ASC LIMIT 100");
```

Yo sé que en PHP existe el operador == eso forzaría a la búsqueda a que sea exactamente igual al string que se le está solicitando, mi pregunta, es puntual, existe algo similar en Mysql, porque no lo he encontrado en los manuales.

!!!DISCULPEN a toda la Comunidad!!! pero ya encontré mi falla. No tiene nada que ver con la sentencia, sino con la forma como codifique mi script.

Lo que pasa es lo siguiente, yo estoy tratando de crear un buscador donde existe 8 opciones, en teoría, estas opciones son filtros y deberían funcionar, pero qué pasa.

Si seleccionas 1 sola opción muestra todos los inmuebles con esa sola opción y así se van sumando las opciones hasta completar las 8 opciones seleccionadas.

Qué pasó, esto:

```
if(!empty($operacion)) {
  ##el codigo
}
elseif (!empty($operacion) AND !empty($tipo)) {
  ##3el codigo
}
```

En ambos casos $operacion no es un string vacío "", por lo tanto se van a ejecutar ambas sentencias, pero si eliminó el primer if, la sentencia se ejecuta perfecto.

Perdonen mi ignorancia, :-(

Comment: Intenta usar `LIKE` en lugar de `=`.

Comment: No funciona, lo extraño es que cuando realizó la consulta en phpmyadmin si me lo hace.

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$busqueda = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM inmuebles WHERE operacion = '" . trim($operacion) . "' AND tipo = '" . trim($tipo) . "' ORDER BY precio_dolar ASC LIMIT 100");`

Comment: ¿Podes mostrarnos como se ve la string de la consulta una vez que php interpola las variables? Eso ayudaria a comprender el resultado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, pero mi falla es de programación no de sentencia, tengo que buscar la forma de lograr esto. Gracias a la comunidad.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Ten en cuenta que esto no es un foro ni nada parecido y que las preguntas que se plantean y sus soluciones no están solamente en función tuya, sino de todos. Es un error en la misma pregunta intentar responder. Si encontraste una solución la puedes aportar tú mismo, pero como respuesta, no en la pregunta. Aún así considero que la solución que estás enfocando no es óptima, ni tampoco el diseño de la base de datos. Deberías tener al menos otra tabla `operaciones` donde registres los tipos de operaciones y relacionar por un id numérico en la tabla `inmuebles`...

Answer (score 0):

Intenta primero obtener la consulta con los **parámetros que envías** y verificar que este todo bien, después copia esa consulta y ejecútala en **phpMyAdmin** para descartar posibles errores.

```
/* Las funciones print_r() y exit() las remueves una vez que obtengas la consulta. */

$q = "SELECT * FROM inmuebles WHERE operacion = '$operacion' AND tipo = '$tipo' ORDER BY precio_dolar ASC LIMIT 100";

print_r($q);
exit();

$busqueda = $conexion->query($q);
```

Comment: Ya descubrí mi falla, es un error de programación, tengo que modificar mi código completo para que funcione.